# Show several PDF in a html page

Tags: php, pdf

I have several PDF documents on my server, so I want to show them inside my html page, in one go, mixing these documents with html texts, images, generating only a page to be printed by the user. Is there a way to get it using PHP?
Some documents have more than one page. So I think using the object element will not resolve the problem because it requires a prefixed height.

Comment: not exactly a php solution, but maybe worth a try: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need convert your PDF into HTML... see this library [pdftohtml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/).

Answer (score 0):

A PDF files' source code is not HTML so a PDF file always needs to be opened using a plugin which can interpret the code. Plugins generally take over the entire page and don't mix with HTML. The only exception I know of is SWF files.

An `<iframe>` solution would look like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>First PDF</h1>
    <iframe src="pdf1.pdf"></iframe>
    <br>
    <img src="image_1.png">
    <br>
    <br>

    <h1>Second PDF</h1>
    <iframe src="pdf2.pdf"></iframe>
    <br>
    <img src="image_2.png">
</body>
```

Please note that simply printing the page will have undesireable and unpredictable outcomes.

If you know that your user-base will be HTML5 compliant then you can look into [embed](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp)

**Other ideas:**

[Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

I have a series of td's in a table that can be clicked and it shows the .pdf.

Here's the code

```
$("#patienttable").on("click", "td#clickforpdf", function(e){
                      var imagetr = $(this).html();
                      if (imagetr.length > 1)
                         {
                          window.open('imagingpdf/' + imagetr, 'Report', 'fullscreen=no'); return false;
                          } else {
                          return false;
                          }
                                                             });
```

Seems to work for me, using window.open - doesn't seem to need sizing.